# How do I prove this divisibility by 17 method?

Tags: divisibility

Take any number. Drop the final two digits. Subtract from it nine times the
number made by the two digits you dropped. The original number and the new
number are either both divisible by 17 or both not divisible by 17.

Comment: can you illustrate by an example.

Comment: Hint: generalize to showing for any two integers $a, b$, $17 \mid 100a+b \Leftrightarrow 17 \mid a-9b$.  Use arithmetic $\pmod{17}$.

Answer (score 1):

Write your initial number $n$ as $n=100a+b$ where $b$ is the last two digits.  You are then claiming that $100a+b \equiv 0 \pmod {17} \iff a-9b \equiv 0 \pmod {17}$  We have $100a+b \equiv -2a+b\pmod {17}$  Then if $-2a+b\equiv 0 \pmod {17}$ we can multiply it by $8$ and get $-16a+8b\equiv a-9b \equiv 0 \pmod {17}$  To go the other way we multiply $a-9b\equiv 0 \pmod {17}$ by $-2$ and retrace the steps.

Answer (score 1):

So your original number is $100a+b$. Then your new number is $a-9b$. Their difference is $99a+10b=6\times17a-3a-7b+17b\equiv-3a-7b\pmod{17}$. But, since $-3$ and $17$ are coprime,\begin{align*}a-9b\equiv0\pmod{17}&\Longleftrightarrow-3a+27b\equiv0\pmod{17}\\&\Longleftrightarrow-3a-7b\equiv0\pmod{17}\text,\end{align*}because $27\equiv-7\pmod{17}.$